# set the properties of a class fixed once in order to avoid tedious calculation

Tags: python, class, numpy, attributes

I have two classes, namely `PositionsD` and `makemock` which are defined as following:

```
import numpy as np
cdef class PositionsD(object):

     property x:
         def __get__(self):
             return np.array(self._x)
         def __set__(self,  x):
             self._x = x

     property y:
         def __get__(self):
             return np.array(self._y)
         def __set__(self, y):
             self._y = y
 def __init__(self, positions):
     self._x = positions[:,0]
     self._y = positions[:,1]

class makemock(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.scale = 0.238
        self.arcsec2rad = np.pi/180./60./60.
        self.g1 = None
        self.g2 = None
        self.source_pos = None
        self.z = None
        self.h_pos = None
        self.h_z = None

    def get_pos(self): 
        return PositionsD(self.source_pos)
    pos = property(get_shear_pos)

    def get_center(self): 
        return PositionsD(self.h_pos)
    center = property(get_center)

    def get_dist(self):
        dx_mpc = (self.pos.x-self.center.x)*self.arcsec2rad*self.scale
        dy_mpc = (self.pos.y-self.center.y)*self.arcsec2rad*self.scale 
        return np.vectorize(complex)(dx_mpc, dy_mpc)  
    dist = property(get_dist)

    def get_r(self):
        return abs(self.dist)  
    r = property(get_r)

    def get_norm(self):
        return -self.dist/np.conjugate(self.dist)
    norm = property(get_norm)  


    def get_gabs(self):
        return np.sqrt(self.g1**2 + self.g2**2 )
    gabs = property(get_gabs)

    def get_g(self):
        phiell=np.arctan2(self.g2, self.g1) /2.
        phipos=np.arctan2( (self.pos.y-self.center.y), (self.pos.x-self.center.x) )
        et = -self.gabs * np.cos( 2*(phiell-phipos) )
        ec = -self.gabs * np.sin( 2*(phiell-phipos) )
        return np.vectorize(complex)(et, ec) 
    obs_g = property(get_g)

    def data2model(self,params):
        rs = params
        x  = self.r/rs
        P  = len(self.r)
        gamma  = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')
        kappa  = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')
        farcth = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')

        m1 = np.where(x < 1.0)[0]
        kappa[m1] = 2/(x[m1]**2 - 1) * \
             (1 - np.log((1 + ((1 - x[m1])/(x[m1] + 1))**0.5)/(1 - ((1 - x[m1])/(x[m1] + 1))**0.5))/(1 - x[m1]**2)**0.5)

        farcth[m1]=0.5*np.log((1.+((1.-x[m1])/(x[m1]+1.))**0.5)/(1.-((1.-x[m1])/(x[m1]+1.))**0.5))/(1-x[m1]**2)**0.5

        gamma[m1] = 4*(np.log(x[m1]/2) + 2*farcth[m1]) * x[m1]**(-2) - kappa[m1]
        model_g = self.norm* gamma /(1. - kappa )
        e = (self.obs_g+model_g)/(1+np.conjugate(model_g)*self.obs_g)
        mask=(abs(model_g)>1.)
        if (np.sum(mask)>0):
        e[mask]=1./np.conjugate(e[mask])
        return e
```

**My Question is:**

I need to run the `data2model` method from `makemock` in a loop for different values of `params`. I figured the process is quite slow while it seems each time in the loop properties of a class such as `r`, `dist`, `obs_g` get computed in each iteration. Is there any way to set them once, in order to increase the speed of loop?

Comment: Have you tried making an object, and then accessing the various properties in a timeit loop?  If so do any take longer than others?  Also if calculating single values, as opposed to large arrays, `math.sin` may be faster than `np.sin` etc.  Can these properties change after an object is created, or are they fixed?  If fixed, you might want to make the attributes rather than properties.

Comment: @hpaulj I posted an anwer. What do you think of this way to save time and speed up the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around to find a way to initialize some instances at the begining and avoid calculating them in each iteration of each function, I found out it is the best to use a `dict` and leave the value of each instance in this dictionary and `update` them at the end of initializing the instances. That is my solution:

```
class makemock(object):
    def __init__(self, g1, g2, source_pos, z, h_pos, h_z, **kw):
        self.scale = 0.238
        self.arcsec2rad = np.pi/180./60./60.
        self.g1 = g1
        self.g2 = g2
        self.source_pos = source_pos
        self.z = z
        self.h_pos = h_pos
        self.h_z = h_z
        pos= PositionsD(self.source_pos)
        center=PositionsD(self.h_pos)
        dx_mpc = (pos.x-center.x)*self.arcsec2rad*self.scale
        dy_mpc = (pos.y-center.y)*self.arcsec2rad*self.scale 
        dist= np.vectorize(complex)(dx_mpc, dy_mpc)  
        r= abs(dist)  
        norm= -dist/np.conjugate(dist)
        gabs= np.sqrt(self.g1**2 + self.g2**2 )

        phiell=np.arctan2(self.g2, self.g1) /2.
        phipos=np.arctan2( (pos.y-center.y), (pos.x-center.x) )
        et = -gabs * np.cos( 2*(phiell-phipos) )
        ec = -gabs * np.sin( 2*(phiell-phipos) )
        obs_g=np.vectorize(complex)(et, ec) 
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        del kw
        self.__dict__.update(locals()) 
        del self.self
    def dump(self):
        print repr(self.__dict__)


    def data2model(self,params):
        rs = params
        x  = self.r/rs
        P  = len(self.r)
        gamma  = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')
        kappa  = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')
        farcth = np.zeros((P,), dtype=np.float64, order='C')

        m1 = np.where(x < 1.0)[0]
        kappa[m1] = 2/(x[m1]**2 - 1) * \
             (1 - np.log((1 + ((1 - x[m1])/(x[m1] + 1))**0.5)/(1 - ((1 - x[m1])/(x[m1] + 1))**0.5))/(1 - x[m1]**2)**0.5)

        farcth[m1]=0.5*np.log((1.+((1.-x[m1])/(x[m1]+1.))**0.5)/(1.-((1.-x[m1])/(x[m1]+1.))**0.5))/(1-x[m1]**2)**0.5

        gamma[m1] = 4*(np.log(x[m1]/2) + 2*farcth[m1]) * x[m1]**(-2) - kappa[m1]
        model_g = self.norm* gamma /(1. - kappa )
        e = (self.obs_g+model_g)/(1+np.conjugate(model_g)*self.obs_g)
        mask=(abs(model_g)>1.)
        if (np.sum(mask)>0):
        e[mask]=1./np.conjugate(e[mask])
        return e
```